# How to get cropped image as a new image using Javascript or HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

In my Phonegap app, when a user chooses an image from gallery, the user should be allowed to crop the image then after clicking submit button, that cropped image should be converted to .png or .jpeg format so that I can send this image to the server. How can I do this using JavaScript or jquery or HTML5. I searched for the sollution but nothing is working. Please help me.

Comment: You say "nothing is working". What did you try, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML5 canvas to crop an image.

See [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/) for more information:

> To crop an image using HTML5 Canvas, we can add six additional arguments to the
>   `drawImage()` method; `sourceX`, `sourceY`, `sourceWidth`, `sourceHeight`, `destWidth` and
>   `destHeight`.  These arguments define the location and size of a rectangle that we want to
>   cut out of an image.

```
<script>
  context.drawImage(imageObj, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
</script>
```

**Update**:

In order to get the cropped image in a format you can send to the server, you can use the [canvas.toDataURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975241.aspx) method.  (Note that IE9 only supports this when your document is actually running in IE9 [document mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I did drawing the image using drawImage but I need the cropped image in either .png or .jpeg format so that I can send this to server.

Comment: Yes I tried using canvas.toDataURL, but problem is it is not supported in ver2.3.3 Android devices.. so need some other way:(

Comment: Ah. Then I’m afraid it’s not possible using HTML5 only.  Perhaps the PhoneGap APIs can provide a solution to this, but I’m not familiar with it, sorry.

Comment: Hmmm it's ok even in Phonegap image editing and saving is not given so will try some other to get the work done.